# Can an external drive be sabotaged by the manufacturer so can't be used internally?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I might have made a $150 mistake. I saw a WD MyBook 8TB External Drive for $150, and thought that it was quite a bargain and wanted to use it as an internal drive on my  2010 Mac Pro tower.

Before cracking it open, I partitioned/formatted to a Mac OS format.
Now, when put inside a Mac, it’s not seen at all. The usual “Can’t recognize drive” message doesn’t appear, nor can I access it via disk utility.

I wrote to Western Digital, and got a canned reply. My question was whether the WD80EZAZ drive was built in a way that it would not function without the PC board that converts from SATA to USB? I am looking for confirmation that this type of sabotage is possible, and if there is any work-around.

FWIW, I saw this other question “[Converting an external hard drive to internal](https://superuser.com/questions/115123/converting-an-external-hard-drive-to-internal)” but in that case, the drive functioned fine, and I’ve done this before with other drives, which is why this caught me by surprise.

Comment: It might be possible, but IMO the only company that would do that is Apple. Are you sure the drive is getting power? (You might be able to hear/fell it spinning up when the computer is switched on.) Have you tried putting the drive back on the SATA to USB adapter?

Comment: Are you sure your Mac can take hard drives this big?

Comment: Two ideas: 1) The SATA power connector can (should) provide 3.3, 5 and 12v power. But many modern drives no longer need the 12v.  Does the Mac supply +12v (just in case that this particular drive does need it?  2) Some drives can be jumpered not to spin up until they receive a start command. Quite useful to prevent a large power surge at power on time of a PC with dozens of drives. And often seen in SCSI & SAS RAID cards. SO basically, what happens when you send this drive a 'start, spin up' command via mac equivalent of hdparms?